# dynamic search using firebase and dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a ui form for advanced search. So its basically like a map of searFiled and values. I do not want to write functions for search possible combination like following

```
collectionRef.where("fname", isEqual:'akshay').where(secondCondtion).
```

So what I want to do this has a function like following and implement it.

```
search(String collection, Map<String,dynamic> filters)
```

How do I implement this? How do use filters and create a query object?

Note: I am new to dart.

Edit1:
So i think this can be achieved by having a variable which can hold named property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `where` it returns a new query, so you can loop over the filters and add them one by one with something like:

```
  void search(String collection, Map<String,dynamic> filters) {
    Query query = collectionRef;
    filters.forEach((field, value) {
      query = query.where(field, isEqualTo: value);
    })
    query.getDocuments()...
  }
```

Comment: The operator not always isEualTo. Sorry but am new to dart but is there any data type that can hold isEqualTo operator?

Comment: So what if think i need is a way to hold variable to hold of type named property. See my edit1

Comment: If you have different operators, you'll need some conditionals in the loop to sort those out. But the basic approach is what I've shown here: loop over the filters and build a new query on each iteration.